# How to move every file in a folder to a subdirectory of the same name?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

Say I have a bunch of files in a directory

```
filename-1.ext1
filename-1.ext2
filename-1.ext3
filename-2.ext1
filename-2.ext2
filename-2.ext3
filename-3.ext1
filename-3.ext2
filename-3.ext3
```

I then want to create subdirectories in the same directory of the same name as the files (filename but no ext) and move them in like this

```
filename-1
├──filename-1.ext1
├──filename-1.ext2
└──filename-1.ext3
filename-2
├──filename-2.ext1
├──filename-2.ext2
└──filename-2.ext3
filename-3
├──filename-3.ext1
├──filename-3.ext2
└──filename-3.ext3
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Edit: ext1, ext2, ext3 are just to indicate three distinct filenames, like .foo, .bar, .top, .coffee etc. Not that the filenames are similar.

Comment: your last paragraph invalidates 3 of below answers which it says file's suffix length are vary but your give sample it's not saying the same, and it says all are in same length and importantly same string with different ending number. please [edit] your sample to reflect your described context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `zsh`, this could be done like so:

```bsh
for name (*.ext<->(.)) mkdir -p -- $name:r && mv -- $name $name:r
```

or using the more familiar long form of the `for` loop,

```bsh
for name in *.ext<->(.); do
    mkdir -p -- $name:r &&
    mv -- $name $name:r
done
```

This iterates over all regular files matching the pattern `*.ext<->` where `<->` match any number.  It's the glob qualifier `(.)` that enforces the matching of only regular files. Change the whole pattern to `*.*(.)` if you want to match any regular file's filename that contains a dot; we require the dot to be present as you wish to remove a filename extension later. To use a stricter rather than looser pattern, use something like `filename-<->.ext<->(.)`.  This pattern requires you to know that you want to match names starting with the string `filename-`.

The `$name:r` expansion will result in the same value as `$name`, but without the extension (i.e., only the value's "root").

We use `--` to signal the end of options to both `mkdir` and  `mv` to stop names beginning with a dash from being mistaken for options.

Comment: This one worked beautifully, I just edited the `(*.ext<->(.))` part with `(*.{123,456,789})` (desired extensions) and it perfomed a charm. What I was looking for wast the `:r` zsh expansion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this `for` loop which is compatible with both bash and zsh shells:

```bsh
for file in *.*; do
  [ -f "$file" ] &&
    mkdir -p -- "${file%.*}" &&
    mv -- "$file" "${file%.*}/"
done
```

- `-p` option in `mkdir` makes sure file exists error is not raised
- `%.*` strips the extension from the filenames.

Comment: This one works a charm when the extensions are actually ext*, but how would you change it if the extensions were for example .foo, .bar, .wex (ergo, non-sequential)?

Comment: @dfelix Updated snippet. The snippet is compatible with both bash and zsh

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, done

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To minimise the number of calls to `mkdir` and `mv`, as a variation on [@they's answer](/a/674589), you could record the list of files that go into a given directory NUL-delimited in an associative array:

```
typeset -A files
for name (*.ext<->(NoN.)) files[$name:r]+=$name$'\0'
mkdir -p -- ${(k)files} &&
  for dir (${(k)files}) mv -- ${(0)files[$dir]} $dir/
```

Beside the features [already described by @they](/a/674589), we have:

- `scalar+=text` append text to a scalar variable (here an element of the `$files` associative array.
- `$'\0'`: The NUL character which is guaranteed not to occur in a file name. We could also have used `/`, and use `(s[/])` instead of `(0)` below.
- `${(k)files}` expands to the non-empty keys of the associative array (here, keys can't be empty as we don't include hidden files and anyway we wouldn't be able to create a directory with an empty name anyway).
- `${(0)param}` splits the parameter expansion on NULs, remove empty elements after splitting.
- I've also added the `N` (nullglob) qualifier to avoid reporting an error if there's no matching file, and `oN` (`o`rders `N`ot) as we don't care about having a sorted list here (and in any case `${(k)hash}` order is unspecified).

Replace `*.ext<->` with `*.*` for files with any extension or `*.(mkv|mov|avi)` for a specific set of extensions. Do not use `*.{mkv,mov,avi}` as that's not a glob operator and would expand to 3 distinct globs.

Answer (score 1):

With `zmv`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
mkmv() { mkdir -p -- $2:h && mv -- "$@"; }

zmv -P mkmv -n '(*).ext<->(#q.)' '$1/$f'
```

(remove `-n` when happy).

That way, you benefit from `zmv`'s sanity checks.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU parallel (a tool I just starting to realise the power of):

```
ls | parallel 'mkdir -p {.}; mv -i {} {.}'
```

As this is not CPU bound in any way, I guess `parallel` won't give any speed advantages, but it's still shorter than many of the other given solutions.

And this doesn't rely on the pattern of filenames.

Comment: You're missing the `--`s and would want to separate the two commands with `&&` instead of `;`. That assumes file names don't contain newline characters and all contain at least one `.`. It's missing the restriction to regular files (or at least filter out directories) that most other answers cover.

Comment: It probably would be better to separate the commands with `&&` instead of `;`. And adding `--` to both `mkdir` and `mv` would make this handle filenames beginning with a dash. In the presence of filenames without a `.`, `mkdir` would fail, the easiest way to deal with that is probably to add `-- *.*` to `ls`. To handle the presence of non-files you can add `()` around the `mkdir` and `mv` coammands and prefix the entire (now parenthesised) command with `[ -f {} ] &&`.

Comment: Another option for dealing with both non-files and the presence of files with a `.` in the name, is to use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.\*` instead of `ls`.

Comment: `parallel` can take its input from the command line rather than stdin or take NUL-delimited records on stdin which would allow it to cope with arbitrary file names. Generally speaking you can't store a list of files in newline delimited records.